# Customize Status Bar with Image-view and text-view in material design

Tags: android, material-design, statusbar

From material design concept on wards,I have seen that we can change the color of status bar.Along with changing the color, I would like to show one image with textview.

Does anyone know how to do this if it is possible?

Please refer to sample screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, here's no API in any of the released Android versions that allows you to customize the status bar other than hiding it or changing the color.

So, the answer to the question is no, it can't be done.

Now, what you can do is add a layout above (or even better below) the Toolbar to display the elements you want to display